# How to UPDATE one column based on the MAX DATE from another column MySQL

Tags: mysql

-I am performing an update on a column in my table. However I would like tp perform the UPDATE only on the rows based on the MAX date from another column in that table. As can be seen below usually the Category column needs to be updated whenever the date is the MAX in the DATE column.

For now It is somewhat manual work as I have to explicitly define the date  like in the code below. 
I would like the code to be something like Update only when DATE IS MAX.

Date format is YYYY-MM-DD

```
Product Number  Date        category
A               2018-01-01   x 
B               2019-01-01   y
C               2020-01-01   z   
D               2021-01-01       


UPDATE SALES_TOTAL LEFT JOIN Masterdata_MAPEBIAS on SALES_TOTAL.`Product Number` = Masterdata_MAPEBIAS.`Item` and Date = '2021/01/01'
SET
SALES_TOTAL.`Category` = Masterdata_MAPEBIAS.Category;
```

Comment: I can't really think why you'd have a left join on an update

Comment: @strawberry Each month I add new data to this table, however one column , namely Category is empty because I need to get this information from another static Lookup up table that has this info. Hence I need an update and a left join to accomplish this. This table is then loaded into Tableau. Do you suggest another alternative ?

Comment: Sorry. That logic escapes me.

Answer (score 1):

Join against a sub-query that gets the max date. I also made use of alias to make the query easier to read

```
UPDATE sales_total t
LEFT JOIN Masterdata_MAPEBIAS m  ON t.`Product Number` = m.item
JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) max_date FROM sales_total) max ON max.max_date = t.sales_date
SET t.category = m.category
```